# How can I pass the vertices position to my vertex shader. I wrote a shader that is not drawing anything to the screen

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I wrote a shader program that is not drawing anything to the screen, I think it's because I may be missed something, I don't know how to pass the vertices position to it.

My vertex shader is:

```
#version 130

in vec2 vertexPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position.xy=vertexPosition;
    gl_Position.z=-1.0;
    gl_Position.w=1.0;
}
```

My fragment shader is:

```
#version 130

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    color=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
}
```

this is the code:

```
 GLfloat triangle []
    {
        200,200,
        400,200,
        400,400
    };
    //translating the coordinates
    glViewport(0,0,640,480);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,640,0,480,0,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();


    GLuint triangleBufferID;//store the identifier of this buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &triangleBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBufferID); 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle), triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW); //describe the data in the buffer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //enable the buffer
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); //Get the pointer for the buffer.

    //SECOND SHADER TYPE (READ FROM FILE):
    const GLchar* vertexshaderPath = "vertexshader.vsh";
    const GLchar* fragmentshaderPath = "fragmentshader.fsh";
    string vertexshaderSource = ""; //getting a string to store the source code of vertexshader.vsh
    string fragmentshaderSource = ""; //getting a string to store the source code of fragmentshader.fsh
    ifstream vertexfile; //getting a file pointer for vertexshader.vsh;
    ifstream fragmentfile; //getting a file pointer for fragmentshader.fsh;
    vertexfile.exceptions (ifstream::badbit); //add exceptions to the file pointer;
    fragmentfile.exceptions (ifstream::badbit); //add exceptions to the file pointer;
    try 
    {
        vertexfile.open(vertexshaderPath); //open vertexshader.vsh
        fragmentfile.open(fragmentshaderPath); //open fragmentshader.fsh
        stringstream vfstream, ffstream; //get two stringstream object;
        vfstream << vertexfile.rdbuf(); //get the content of vertexshader.vsh into a stringstream;
        ffstream << fragmentfile.rdbuf(); //get the content of fragmentshader.fsh into a stringstream;
        vertexfile.close(); //close the file;
        fragmentfile.close(); //close the file;
        vertexshaderSource=vfstream.str(); //copy the string from stringstream into vertexshaderSource;
        fragmentshaderSource=ffstream.str(); //copy the string from stringstream into fragmentshaderSource;
    }
    catch (ifstream::failure e) //if failure caught...
    {
        cout << "Error, file is unreadable!" << endl;
    }
    const GLchar* vscode = vertexshaderSource.c_str();
    //converted into c_str();
    const GLchar* fscode = fragmentshaderSource.c_str(); 
    //converted into c_str();

    //THIS PART FOR ALL WAYS:
    GLuint vertexshaderID=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); //create a shader
    glShaderSource(vertexshaderID,1,&vscode,nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertexshaderID); //compile shader;
    GLint success;
    GLchar infolog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexshaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) //check the compilation results
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexshaderID,512,0,infolog);
        cout << "Error vertex shader's compilation failed" << endl;
        cout << infolog << endl;
    }
    GLuint fragmentshaderID=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); //create a shader
    glShaderSource(fragmentshaderID,1,&fscode, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentshaderID); //compile shader
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentshaderID,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);
    if(!success) //check the compilation results
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentshaderID,512,0,infolog);
        cout << "Error fragment shader's compilation failed" << endl;
        cout << infolog << endl;
    }
    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram(); //create a program;
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexshaderID); //attach vertexshader to the program;
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentshaderID); //attach fragmentshader to the program;

    glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "vertexPosition");
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "color"),1.0,0.0,0.0);

    glLinkProgram(programID); //link the pieces of the program;
    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) //check the link status;
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programID,512,0,infolog);
        cout << "Error linking the program" << endl;
        cout << infolog << endl;
    }
  //  glDeleteShader(vertexshaderID);
//    glDeleteShader(fragmentshaderID);

    glUseProgram(programID); //use the program;
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code:

There is code used to initialize buffers and shaders mixed with code that has to be called in each frame. For example, shader loading should definitely be done only once, but the draw-calls have to happen every frame.

Then, you are mixing fixed-function code (`glMatrixMode` and related functions) with core profile code. Most probabibly the problem is, that all the transformations applied here are not used (since the matrix stack is not used when working in core profile with shaders). Thus the coordinates used (from 200 to 400) are outside of the default view frustum (ranging from -1 to 1). You will have to implement the transformations somewhere in the shader to get a correct projection of your points to NDC.

<s>Minor: There is no guarantee that `vertexPosition` will be on location 0 (although this might be the case).</s>

Comment: Oh, and `glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "color"),1.0,0.0,0.0);` needs to come *after* successfully linking the program, not before.

Comment: "*There is no guarantee that `vertexPosition` will be on location 0*" Actually, since he used `glBindAttribLocation` before linking the program, he's guaranteed that it will be.